# Views get stuck on Top Left Corner (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I'm a begginer in Android Development so I decided to download Android Studio.
I created a project and in my first couple of times trying to build the App the compiler gave a an error because I was missing some files so I installed them.

My problem is that when it finally finished building the App I couldn't see the *Hello Word* text view even though it was displayed that it existed in the Component Tree, I add another text view and it disappeared as soon as I released the mouse button. This also happened with all the other Components that I tried with, buttons, images, views, everything.

I also noticed that by clicking one of the Components on the Component Tree in the top left corner there would show up 2 buttons: one with a symbol that imo means that it should remove the component from the Layout and another with an "ab" that I don't know what it means. This indicated me that the Components should be stuck in there for some reason.

Thank you for your attention,

João Oliveira

P.S.:

Links
[Components seem to be stuck in the Top Left Corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDirZ.png)
[Text View is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxH8t.png)

XML text in activity_mail.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sample_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You have forget to add closing tag of contraint layout 
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Check it out If it works

Comment: @Opriday It's closed but not on that line, after _tools:context=".MainActivity"_ there is a closing brackets. I haven't messed around with any view except the Design view. Do you have any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Which SDK and support version are you targeting? I noticed that using 28.0.0-alpha3 gives errors in the preview although the app builds and runs as expected. Try changing SDK to 27 and support to 27.0.0.

Comment: android-26 means, Go to skd manager, Sdk platform then check  API level 26 platform installed or not. If not installed then installed and sync gradle or rebuild the project.

Comment: Check this link If you still have issue: https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-26-in/13827

Answer (score 0):

Your views are right there where you constraint them. And a view of size 1dp is not visible, this is your code:

```
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="1dp"
```

Make the view to be the right size and you will see it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer what should I change the values to?

Comment: `wrap_content` or a value that's large enough to show the view

Comment: I changed it but no changes. Check my post I updated the xml file

Comment: Copy and paste your xml exactly as it is without leading spaces and with the closing tag of constraint layout.

Comment: I fixed it @mTak

Comment: Your code is fine. Go to your xml, open your preview if it's not open and click on this line: `android:text="Hello World!"`. Now you should see the borders of the TextView in preview

Comment: Do you see it now?

Comment: No @mTak, but I changed the Device in preview to a Wear Device, both the TextViews show up and I can move them around. I tried changing back to a Phone or any of the other devices, text views don't show up and are stuck on Top Left corner just like before.

Comment: I'll try that out and as soon as I'm able to do that I'll report back

Comment: I tested running the app on the emulator and it worked out fine. Probably there is something wrong with the preview Window. Can you suggest me any link to where I can troubleshoot it? Anyways, thank you so much for your time. Regards, João

Comment: Try Build/clean project and if needed File/invalidate cashes/Restart... Sometimes they fix problems. Also in design view Force Refresh Layout in the blue icon up left

Comment: Ok it just noticed that there was a red warning sign. I did a quick google search with the error and found the solution. Apparently the problem is in app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml I had to change Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar  in to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Yep that seems to be what it SHOULD look like. I don't really know where the problem is coming from.